# MySQL 8 Innodb clustering add instance error

Tags: mysql, mysql-8.0, mysql-innodb-cluster

During MySQL 8 innodb clustering add instance.

Cluster.addInstance: The port '33101' for localAddress option is already in use. Specify an available port to be used with localAddress option or free port '33101'. (RuntimeError)

Please let me know how can solve.

Comment: MySQL is running on port 3310

Comment: Are you sure there isn't a typo in the settings?

Comment: No such type mistake in the settings